# Which compiler is used to produce Microsoft Office for Mac?

Tags: c++, macos, compiler-construction, com

We knew Microsoft Office has Mac edition.

Just curious, who knows which compiler is used to produce Microsoft Office for Mac?

When I looked at the Windows SDK header "Windows.h", I find following code snippet:

```
#ifndef _MAC
#if defined(_68K_) || defined(_MPPC_)
#define _MAC
#endif
#endif
```

Does Microsoft have a private C++ compiler for Mac? If so, I guess the compiler must support COM (Component Object Model), whereas gcc does not. ('Support' means can product COM-compliant C++ object)

Comment: Seems off-topic but still an interesting question (+1). I can't think of a more suitable site just now, so I'm not voting to close.

Comment: http://www.schwieb.com/blog/2006/06/02/a-brief-history-of-mac-office/ and http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rick_schaut/archive/2006/06/03/616209.aspx seem to indicate MSVC at first, then CodeWarrior, and then XCode.

Comment: @Raymond - The 68k was found in the original 1984 Mac. At about that time, the MS C compiler could target it. Not anymore.

Comment: That is to say, MS has two code base for Office? Xcode means gcc or clang, Office can build with gcc???!!!

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft does not have a private compiler for OS X. [xcode](/questions/tagged/xcode)  [uses](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xcode#Composition.)  [gcc](/questions/tagged/gcc), [llvm](/questions/tagged/llvm),  [or both](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xcode#Composition.).

This means, depending on the version of Xcode used, Microsoft Office for Mac builds with either gcc or clang.  Note that this does not necessarily imply that Microsoft uses the Xcode IDE.

Answer (score 0):

From http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Office_for_Mac_2011 its says it it is written in 
Cocoa. Cocoa is Apple's native object-oriented application programming interface (API) for the Mac OS X operating system.
for more info see this..
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cocoa_%28API%29

May be Apple LLVM compiler which is include in Xcode and Xcode is the best available developer tool package for Cocoa and Cocoa touch frameworks..

Comment: The Wiki article contradicts itself. It also says it is 'written to the Cocoa API' which at least makes sense. Clearly the sidebar statement that it is 'written in Cocoa' is wrong. *Was* wrong, I fixed it. The sidebar link is to the Cocoa API page.